# Display the speed of a Dc motor

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, motor, sensor, speed

I have an industrial rotating machine (huge dimensions) working with a DC motor, there is a button that changes its speed but the value of this speed is not displayed.
is there a circuit that measures and displays this speed that can work for this type of machine with great dimensions?

Comment: What's the nominal rotation rate? How much can it be varied using the button?

Comment: the nominal speed is 1150 rpm and the speed varies significantly using the button

Answer (score 2):

There's many different kinds of tachometers available commercially. From things that just count how many times a reflective sticker on your machines rotating parts passes a light sensor per second, to things that look for periodic EMI on the motor's supply to simply rotary encoders attached mechanically, acoustic sensing followed by four lines of Python signal processing...

Comment: is there any possibility of extracting the information directly from the Dc motor that rotates the machine and displaying this speed on an LCD screen, for example; so that the speed is permanently displayed while changing it?

Comment: You extract the information directly from the motor by placing a reflective tape or paint on part of the shaft and aim a tachometer at it.  There are literally hundreds of these on the market.

Comment: Knowing the voltage, current at certain points in the circuit are no guarantee.  There is an unknown amount of friction and other factors.  It would be like reading the consumption of gasoline on your car to determine speed.  Your car may be going down a hill, or idling. Both would show same gas consumption, but different speeds. Just look at tire speed, and that's accurate. There are many better ways to do it, especially with a contactless setup.  They are dirt cheap and even bench-top drill presses have them these days.

Comment: @Kate in commutated DC motors, the current flow switching over at poles gives a very rhythmic, broadband noise impulse comb. You can measure the frequency of that very reliably.

Comment: @katemoon or did you perhaps mean to comment on Charles Cowe's answer instead of mine?

Comment: I was filling in the blanks of why your answer makes sense.  Btw, can you link one of those devices you mention, the reader of the periodic EMI off the commutators?  Sounds interesting, I haven't ever seen it done that way.

Comment: Don't have a product you can buy, but take a capacitor, couple the noise out of your supply lines into a bit of active filtering, rectify, and feed to your favorite microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

An armature voltmeter would provide a reasonable indication of speed, but you need to know the rated armature voltage. A DC motor that is large would likely have a rating plate providing full details for the motor.

A "button" does not change the speed of a motor. The button must send a command to a speed control unit that adjusts the armature voltage. The speed control unit may have a rating plate and a diagram that would help to determine how to connect a voltmeter that would indicate speed.